# Android: how to get the inputs from layout that was created programmatically?

Tags: android

I have created a row in a table layout dynamically as an event of on click listener, now I'm facing a hard time with getting data from elements of this row which are (1 EditText and 3 Spinners).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 solutions might help here

1) Saving references to these views in Activity class fields

2) Specify id while creating views & use findViewById for access